# Find the outliers or anomaly in gps data (time, latitude, longitude, altitude)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science

I have data. Based on the data (time, latitude, longitude, altitude) determine what are the typical routes that device makes during a full week.
After determining the baseline routes or typical area frequented by device we can start determining an anomaly based on the device traveling outside it’s frequent route/area.

Action: The process will then send an “alert” to the system is traveling outside it’s frequent area route

Please suggest which machine learning algorithm is useful. I am going to start clustering algorithm. Also tell me which python libraries is useful to use machine learning algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, if you use Python, then use scikit-learn.

For this problem, there is multiple possibilities.

One way is indeed to use a clustering algorithm. For this purpose to get the anomaly too, you can use DBSCAN. It is an algorithm designed to get cluster and the outliers.

Another way would be (assuming you have for each device all their position) to use more funny way like a clustering algorithm on all the positions to get the important place, and after an LDA (latent dirichlet allocation) to get the main topics (here the words would be the index of the cluster, the document would be the list of position of each device and so the topics would be the main "routes").